# Selenium - Firefox Options Not Taking Effect

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to change web driver preferences so I can bypass the save/open prompt that pops up when the Firefox webdriver clicks on the download button for a pdf I want.

I am setting the preferences for the Firefox web driver and passing it as a parameter "options" when I initialize the webdriver. It shows that the preferences I enter save into options.preferences but when I have selenium click on the download button on the website, the download prompt for the pdf still pops up.

```
def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.headless = False
        print(options.preferences)
        options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'myDir')
        options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
        print(options.preferences)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)
```

I plan to have this headless, but have it set to False for now. What would be causing the webdriver not to take in the preferences I passed into Options?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. It seems that the firefox pdf previewer was bypassing the settings I was passing through. The line below blocked the preview of the pdf and allowed the automatic download to take effect.

```
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
```